# Show that line segment intersects a set

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, elementary-set-theory

Assume $E ⊂ R^n$ as a set in $R^n$ and we have that $x \in E$ and $ y \in R^n$\E. Using the two elements, show the segment $$[x, y] := \{x + t(y − x) : t ∈ [0, 1]\}$$ intersects $∂E$. Then prove that if R is a rectangle and $x,y \in R$ s.t. $x \in E$ and $ y \in R^n \ E$ then $R \cap ∂E \neq ∅$.

I am not sure what ∂E means is it the closure of a set? and i am not sure what theorems to use to prove this.

Comment: Did you mean "suppose the segment ... intersects $\partial E$"?

Comment: i meant show the segement sorry

Comment: Usually, $\partial E$ would mean the boundary of $E$, not the closure of $E$.

Comment: To be clear, $\partial E = \overline E\cap \overline{\mathbb R^n\setminus E}$ is the boundary of $E$, where the overline denotes closure. The closure of $E$ is the intersection of all closed sets that contain $E$.

Answer (score 0):

The function f:[0,1] -> R$^n$, t -> x + t(y - x) is continuous.
[x,y], the image of [0,1] by f is connected.
Show if every point of [x,y] is not in the boundary, it would be disconnected.

Exercise.
Use that proposition to prove the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: how would i show that if its not in the boundary then it would be disconnected? can you list out some brief steps and hints thanks